# c# How to filter Datagridview bind to dataset - Accent Insentitive

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, dataset, accent-insensitive

I have a `DataGridView` bind to a `DataSet`, some value (Name) have accent (ex: é, í, ž, ć, é, á) and I would to perform a filtering accent insensitive.

Usually I am filtering my `DataGridView` like this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyDataSet.People.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Name LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
    dataGridView1.DataSource = MyDataSet.People.DefaultView;
}
```

I tried to change this in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People] (
[Num]        INT           NOT NULL,
[Name]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);
```

by this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People] (
[Num]        INT           NOT NULL,
[Name]     NVARCHAR (50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NOT NULL
);
```

and tried to change:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyDataSet.People.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Name LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI";
    dataGridView1.DataSource = MyDataSet.People.DefaultView;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer the following decision.

Add to datatable new column named `NameWithoutAccent`.

```
MyDataSet.People.Columns.Add("NameWithoutAccent", typeof(string));
```

Fill this column with values with removed accents. Filtering will occur by this column.

```
foreach (DataRow row in MyDataSet.People.Rows)
{
    string name = (string)row["Name"];
    string nameWithoutAccent = RemoveAccent(name);
    row["NameWithoutAccent"] = nameWithoutAccent;
}
```

First normalize the string to remove the accents with [String.Normalize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eaxk1x2(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Then remove all diacritics with regular expressions. `M` is [Unicode category](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_11) "All diacritic marks".

```
public string RemoveAccent(string name)
{
    string normalizedName = name.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    string pattern = @"\p{M}";
    string nameWithoutAccent = Regex.Replace(normalizedName, pattern, "");
    return nameWithoutAccent;
}
```

Hide this column after data binding.

```
dataGridView1.Columns["NameWithoutAccent"].Visible = false;
```

Input filter is cleaned from accents too.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string nameWithoutAccent = RemoveAccent(textBox1.Text);
    MyDataSet.People.DefaultView.RowFilter = "NameWithoutAccent LIKE '%" + nameWithoutAccent + "%'";
}
```

Comment: I was thinking there was another way to do it but i will do it like that. thanks for your help.